# Change text color in a table cell (if, else)

Tags: jquery, if-statement, text, colors, html-table

If have a table like this..

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="cell1">20</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and so one..with more than one `<td>` of course..

Now i would like to change the color of the text in the `<td>` if the number is smaler than 5.

Is that possible with jQuery?

There is no input-field or paragraph in `<td>`, just text.

Comment: What do you mean by "if the number is smaller than 5"? Do you mean that 20 in the text of the TD, or do you mean the 1 on the cell1 class? Or do you mean the number of TD occurrences?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.cell1').each(function(i, n) {
   if($(n).text() < 5) $(n).css('color', 'green');
});
```

Iterate through each cell, check value, then change accordingly

http://jsfiddle.net/bQfb6/2/

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$("table.myTable td").each(function(){
    if(parseInt($(this).html())<5){
        $(this).addClass("newColor");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test the content of the field like this:

```
$('.cell1').each(function() {
    if($(this).text() < 5) { 
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.** You can use [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop through all the table cells. You can then get the [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) in the cell and [parse it as an integer (base 10)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). If it is less than 5 you can change the [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) [color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/color) to be whatever you want.

I'm assuming that all the numbers are integers and that they do not change after the page is loaded.

For example:

```
$("td").each(function(){
   $cell = $(this);
   if(parseInt($cell.text(),10) < 5){
      $cell.css("color", "red");
   }
});​
```

[**Try it!**](http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/qcENH/)